# swift: image is nil after converting to CIImage

Tags: swift

I am new to swift and I am trying the CoreML feature using React Native.

I have a source file with URL as string. I convert that string to URL using 
`let imageURL = URL(fileURLWithPath: source)`
 and I tried printing out the source which is of type string and it contains the absolutePath to the file 
`file:///var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/9C4D58FD-C817-47CB-A418-04BA30863C24/Library/Caches/Camera/133F8168-356A-436C-B7AF-557FA1C4F68F.jpg"` 
After that, I try to make the `CIImage` by using
 `let image = CIImage.init(contentsOf: imageURL);`

But when I try to print `image`, it returns `nil`. I searched a bit and tried using `guard` but no luck. Any help will be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

The CIImage does not create the image from a server URL. You can achieve this by first downloading the file at local location. And use the local file URL to create CIImage and then set it. The referred question/answer achieves the same, please check [Loading/Downloading image from URL on Swift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24231680/loading-downloading-image-from-url-on-swift/43704819#43704819)

If you still face issues do let me know. All the best!

Comment: Hi, thanks for your reply. As mentioned, I am not downloading the image from any server. I am just clicking a photo and the photo is saved in the local cache.

Comment: Not really, I passed the base64 image instead of the filepath (which kind of solved my issue) but I still want to know how to solve the problem